# In QT qml Tree-view how to get child items as text from treeview using its index

Tags: qt, treeview, qml

```
TreeView {
      anchors.fill: parent
      model: theModel
      onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("current index: " + currentIndex+ " current row: " + currentIndex.row)
      itemDelegate: Rectangle {
                 color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
                 height: 40

                 Text {
                     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                     text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value // The branches don't have a description_role so styleData.value will be undefined
                 }
             }

      TableViewColumn {

          role: "name_role"
          title: "Database name"

      }
      onClicked: {
             console.log("clicked", index)
      }
```

this is my treeview code.it will show database names as parent and table names as the child. I need to get the child name when I click on the child area.
that's all I need.

for eg:

```
database_name
   |____table_one
   |____table_two
```

when i click on 'table_one' i need to get the table_one as a text/string

this is my application I need to get the child items names as a text from this treeview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some search, I have got the solution for the above question myself

```
syntax: model_class_name.data(index,"Role_name");
```

*the above code will return the current item that in focus in a tree view

Answer (score 0):

In the qml file, you must set the class name as `model_class_name.data(index,INT);` where INT - it is a number of role.